# Can we serialize and send a form with a list of objects inside the main object - Ajax, Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am sorry that I cannot share my code. I will try to give an appropriate example for my situation.

Class Person:

```
    public class Community {

       private int personCount;
       private List<Person> persons;

       //getters and setters for all
   }
```

Call Person:

```
   public class Person {

       private int name;
       private int age;

       //getters and setters
  }
```

Now, I want to serialize and send a form with an AJAX call from my JSP. 
In JSP, I used

```
<div th:each="parameter,iterStat : ${persons}" class="personsContainer">
  <div th:text="'Name: ' + ${parameter.name}"></div>
   ...
```

to traverse through the list.

This is the AJAX call

```
   function updateCommunityPeople(initial) {

                var getValuesUrl = /*[[@{/getPeoplesJson}]]*/ "";
                var data = $(".personsContainer").parents('form:first').serialize();

                data += "&initial=" + initial;
                alert("date: "+data);

                $.ajax({
                    'type': "POST",
                    'url': getValuesUrl,
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'data': data,
                })
                .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Updated successfully");
                 });
      }
```

My controller method:

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/getPeoplesJson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getCommunityPeopleValuesJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,
        Locale locale, Model model, Device device, Principal principal, @Valid Community post,
        BindingResult result)
{
    int count = post.getPersonCount();
    if (post != null && post.getPersons() != null)
    {
        //calls to service and so on...
        return "true";
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here, I am able to retrieve the person count correctly but the whole issue is with the list of Persons. It is null always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of persons is always `null` because the jQuery's `serialize()` function takes into account only form elements. From the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Description: Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.
>
> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`: `$( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();`
>
> It is typically easier, however, to select the `<form>` itself for serialization

For example, if you had a `<select multiple>` element and listed the names as options, the serialize function would correctly serialize all selected `<option>` elements:

```
<form>
    <select multiple th:each="parameter,iterStat : ${persons}" class="personsContainer">
        <option selected th:text="'Name: ' + ${parameter.name}"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ab18r8ao/).

**Edit**

To automatically fill in the `persons` list from the form parameters or the query string it will need to be in the following format:

```
personCount=2&persons[0].name=joe&persons[0].age=20&persons[1].name=john&persons[1].age=25`
```

This means your form should look something like this:

```
<form>
    <div th:each="parameter,iterStat : ${persons}" class="personsContainer">
        <input type="text" th:value="${parameter.name}" th:name="'people[' + ${iterStat.index} + '].name'">
        <input type="text" th:value="${parameter.age}" th:name="'age[' + ${iterStat.index} + '].age'">
    </div>
</form>
```

Also, the ajax's `dataType` should be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if you're going to use `serialize()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean it is not possible.  I am not sure if I understood what you meant but this still goes as a parameter at the same level (as a direct property of Community Bean). I wish to know if there is a way to map the values directly to the Person Bean inside Community Bean.

Comment: Thanks for the needful. I did try that way before but probably the server didn't publish properly. I tried it again confidently (because of your answer) and it worked well.